# QtCreator cross compiling Raspberry Pi from Win, issue to run app remotely

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, x11, raspberry-pi2

I'm setting up the environment so that I can build Raspberry Pi apps in Windows 7. Until now compiling is fine, so that I can copy (manually) the app to the Pi and it runs as expected.

Going further, I'm facing difficulties to remotely run my app (gpioapp). Even though I see gpioapp being copied to the Pi, QtCreator do not runs it.

The following message is shown in the QtCreator Application Output:

```
No protocol specified
gpioapp: cannot connect to X server :0.0
Application finished with exit code 1.
```

What can I do in order to investigate/solve this issue?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are deploying this app to the pi? Is it over ssh. If that is the case it likely means that your remote terminal isnt able to access the X server and either needs to be run with -Y or the DISPLAY variable needs to be set correctly in the environment.

Comment: I've configured SSH access through QtCreator menu (Tools>Options>Devices), adding a new device. So I think this is used to deploy. In addition to that, in the .pro file, I've added two lines "target.path = /home/user/Downloads" and "INSTALLS += target". Also, I would like to mention that I can run the app remotely not doing through QtCreator. May I provide more information?

Comment: The only remaining thing that would help, do you want the app to appear on the screen of the pi? Or to be forwarded to the screen of your development machine?

Comment: I want to see the app forwarded to the screen of the development machine.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Vality suggestion to correctly set $DISPLAY, I did the following:

1. Given that I was able to remotely run the app via SmarTTY, then I checked the value of $DISPLAY on it `echo $DISPLAY`:

`localhost:10.0`

2. Went back to QtCreator>Projects (left side) and, in the "Run Environment", changed DISPLAY (from `:0.0`) to `:10.0`

That solved the issue.